# c# Main Class include "subclass"

Tags: c#, call, mainclass

Hey I have two classes

```
class Main
{
    public exLog exLog;
    public Main()
    {

    }
}
```

and

```
class exLog
{
    public exLog()
    {

    }
    public exLog(String where)
    {

    }
    public exLog(String where, String message)
    {

    }
}
```

i tried to call exLog direct without giving exLog a parameter. So I can call any class with the Main Method. 
How should I do that?

```
public String ReadFileString(String fileType, String fileSaveLocation)
{
    try
    {
        return "";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        newMain.exLog("", "");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I like to call them like a funtion in Main

Comment: Read about classes and [Constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx). `Main` in first class is the constructor, so that other *methods* in your other class.

Comment: `public exLog exLog = new exLog();` Side note - class names should start with a capital letter (and fields with a lowercase letter) - that's the fairly universal convention.

Comment: @DStanley fairly universal in C# :).

Comment: @DStanley this public exLog exLog = new exLog(); would say i can only call 1 constructor but I like to call any of these 3 Constructors from another class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methinks you want something like [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

```
class Main
{
    private exLog exLog;
    public Main()
    {

    }

    public void ExLog()
    {
        exLog = new exLog();
    }
    public void ExLog(String where)
    {
        exLog = new exLog(where);
    }
    public void ExLog(String where, String message)
    {
        exLog = new exLog(where, message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it as soon as you instantiate it.

```
public Main()
{
    exLog = new exLog();
    exLog.MethodInClass();
}
```

Also, if you are not in the same assembly you'll need to make exLog public.

Finally, this is C# and the style dictates that class names should be PascalCased.  It's a good habit to form.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused about classes, instances, constructors, and methods.  This does not work:

```
newMain.exLog("", "");
```

because `exLog` in this case is a *property*, not a *method*.  (It's confusing because you use the same name for the class and the property, which is why most conventions discourage that).

You can call a *method* on the *instance*:

```
newMain.exLog.Log("", "");
```

but then you'll need to change the names of the methods (and add a return type) in your `exLog` class so they don't get interpreted as constructors:

```
class exLog
{
    public void Log() 
    {
    }
    public void Log(String where)
    {
    }
    public void Log(String where, String message)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Main
{
    public exLog exLog;
    public Main()
    {
        exLog = new exLog();
        exLog.ReadFileString("", "");
    }
}
```